# Find the law of random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $Y$ have the Poisson distribution
$Y \sim P(\lambda )$ and let $Z = \left\{ \begin{gathered}
  \frac{Y}{2}{\text{ if }}Y{\text{ is even}} \hfill \\
  \frac{{\left( {1 - Y} \right)}}{2}{\text{ if }}Y{\text{ is odd}} \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right.$

How can i find the law of $Z$ ?

Comment: some hints please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $p_Y$, the Poisson distribution

For $k<0$, $P(Z=k)=p_Y(1-2k)$
For $k=0$, $P(Z=0)=p_Y(0)$
For $k>0$, $P(Z=k)=p_Y(2k)$